# How could you build this? It seems really hard to make the lines

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is what I'm trynna achieve but I don't know how to put the lines next to the boxes, what would be a way of doing this? With display or position?

Picture of what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: please add the code for what you have tried so far

Comment: As the lines are a visual guide rather than an integral part of the data in the DOM you could consider drawing them as pseudo elements. You could also make the whole thing responsive by using units relative e.g. to the viewport. Please put the code you have so far so we can see your HTML structure into your question See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: absolute` and some coordinate for that like below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 50px;
}

.item {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 78px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: -1;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  border: solid white;
  border-left: none;
  height: 50%;
}

.div1 {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```